# Swift3 Result of call is unused, but produces 'BFTask<NSNumber>'

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift3

I am iOS app. in Swift3 (Xcode8).
This app. keeps user data in Parse(on Heroku). When I try to delete the user information by following code, it doesn't delete the data and warning says "Result of call is unused, but produces 'BFTask'"  --> for the marked part of the code
I can delete the user data manually from Parse. So, there seems to be no problem on Parse side.
Somebody advise me how exactly I have to do to solve this warning.
or better way to delete the data from Parse object?

```
        isFollowing[followedObjectId] = false

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

        let query = PFQuery(className: "followers")

        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.current()!.objectId!)
        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: userids[indexPath.row])

        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    (object as AnyObject).deleteInBackground() **//this part shows warning**

                }
            }

        })

    }
```

Comment: The standard way of dealing with "result of call is unused" is to assign the result to `_`.  So, `_ = (object as AnyObject).deleteInBackground()`.

Comment: Thanks.  Now the warning is gone but data in the Parse can't be deleted....